# instagram graph api posting carousel error

Tags: python, instagram-api

Trying to upload a carousel post to instagram.
using this [official guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/). it consists of 3 steps, but i can't seem to get through the second step.

```
def carouselcontainer(item_ids,caption):
#Post the Image
    post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{}/media'.format(account_id)
    payload = {
        'caption' : caption,
        'media_type' : 'CAROUSEL',
        'children': item_ids,
        'access_token' : access_token
    }
    r = requests.post(post_url, data=payload)
    print(r.text)
    result = json.loads(r.text)
    if 'id' in result:
         return result['id']
print(carouselcontainer(['17983349911631232', '179288683854321234'],'test caption'))
```

this is the code i used.

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Unsupported post type. The post has too little or too many attachments to qualify as a carousel","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AzcboMr7axTy9Aaqd8eo_K3"}}
```

the error states that i have too little or too many attachments,even though i sent 2 item containers, which should be enough for a carousel container.

Answer (score 1):

Hi your code looks perfect. Just need to change

```
r = requests. Post(post_url, data=payload)
```

to

```
r = requests.Post(post_url, json=payload)
```

since you are passing as data so instead of arrays it was going single element of arrays thats  why getting that error